# Need some help with suspension on Mongoose Salvo Comp FS

Tags: upgrades, full-suspension, adjustment

I'm 14 years old and have been riding for a year on a Mongoose Salvo Comp full-suspension that was bought second hand and in perfect condition.

The bike is great but after riding a friend's bike, I felt my suspension was probably not good or not set up well it was not really doing the job properly. The liquid in them is oil, and they are very hard.

Do you think I should go to a bike shop to review and fix them or just buy new ones? The fork is SR Suntour, can I fit a  Rock Shox or Fox Fork?

Another question is should the suspension be special to my bike model?

Thanks a lot for answering.

Comment: Do you know what year it is? I looked up 2015 spec: SR Suntour XCR Air LO 120mm fork, X-Fusion 02RL shock.

Comment: No, mine is a 2011 model.

Comment: First you should make sure that your fork doesn't have a "lockout", or, if it does, the lockout is not activated.

Comment: It [looks like](http://www.thebikelist.co.uk/2011/mongoose/salvo-comp) the  fork is "Suntour XCR HLO, 120mm travel, magnesium lower, preload adjust and hydraulic lock out". If you're locked out, it'll act rigid. If its not locked out, you can find guides on youtube for servicing it at home (officially Suntour doesn't provide service manual/parts for this fork). Failing that, you can fit another fork (use a shop for compatibility/installation). Also, see our discussion on [preload](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/7813/what-is-the-preload-setting-on-the-front-fork-suspension).

Comment: Thanks, for the help, but what with the back one? can I fit there another shock? and can i get recommendations forks?/ back shocks?

Comment: If the rear shock is borked then you might find a replacement via eBay but check 1) it’s not locked out on the blue lever 2) it’s not inflated too high. Circa 180 psi for a 90kg person is a reference point.